# Should a EULA be translated?

Tags: applications, internationalization

I have a application which will be available in 4 languages: French, German, Danish and English. All the text in the app will be translated, but should the EULA also be translated? What is the common way of handling this? The lawyer has accepted the english version of the EULA and I assume all the translated versions should also be accepted then. Is it okay just to use a English EULA?

Comment: did you find any reasonable compromise somewhere in between 'IP rights do not exist' and 'get a lawyer to signproof each translation'? Of course, _reasonable_ for your case.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a software question, it's a legal question. Ask your lawyer.

Ultimately, it's about this: under which jurisdiction will any EULA violations fall? And does that jurisdiction treat foreign-language license agreements any different than native ones? Does it even recognize EULAs as binding at all? For example, under German law, any EULA that the user only gets to see *after* buying the product is void, so in Germany EULAs are basically legal masturbation. Even in the US, courts have found some EULAs invalid.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: This is not a legal question. My focus is here if its "common" for applications to have translated EULA's and does a french user feel surprised if he see's a english EULA? It has nothing to do with the legal part - as you say, the lawyer takes care of that. So yes it is a software question.

Comment: @s0mmer: I suspect that a large (possibly majority) percentage of users wouldn't even notice what language the EULA they just clicked through was in.

Comment: Top answer. It's not a software question, it's intellectual  property rights licensing question. Apart from the language that might be legally significant, the actual content might need to differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction or otherwise EULA might be invalidated. As an example in USA it's possible to prohibit any reverse engineering but reverse engineering is permitted under a specific set of circumstances by EU law. Setting terms that contradict local laws may void parts or whole of EULA.

Comment: @Totophil: It's not an intellectual property rights question, as there is no such thing as "intellectual property rights." Copyrights are *monopoly rights* and nothing else. To think of them as a property right is fallacious. In addition, reverse engineering in the US is legal, but criminalized only if the device being reversed is a Copyright *management* device. (There's more to it than even that, but this box is so small....)

Comment: @greyfade: It's true that this isn't an IP question, but to say that there's no such thing as intellectual property rights? You might want to read up some: http://www.wipo.int/freepublications/en/intproperty/909/wipo_pub_909.pdf, http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/internal_market/businesses/intellectual_property/index_en.htm.

Comment: @SnOrfus: The problem is that so-called "IP law" is absolutely *not* property law. To call it property law is disingenuous at best. The concept of "intellectual property" was created to confuse everyone into thinking of it as a property right, when it has absolutely nothing to do with property at all. It's a monopoly right. No more, no less. I'm well aware of what "world leaders" say it is, but they're just as confused as the rest of us. Please read [this book](http://goo.gl/WDc3s) and [this](http://goo.gl/T1fDv). (Goo.gl because this box is too small.)

Comment: @greyfade: Interesting looking books. Calling IP a misnomer does nothing to refute that it exists, is legislated and must be adhered to until such a time that it isn't.

Comment: @SnOrfus: To be clear, I'm not saying that it doesn't exist as a matter of law, I'm saying that the whole concept is fallacious and distracts us from what the law actually *says.* And it *says* that it's a monopoly right, and it is found nowhere near the books on property law. (Laws like "Pro-IP" notwithstanding.)

Comment: @s0mmer: It *IS* a legal question.  Translations are necessarily imperfect.  An imperfection in the translation can introduce a meaning change in a document, causing an end user to believe that something is OK when the author's intent was quite the opposite.  At the very least, the attorneys must sign off on the translations of the EULA, as well as the original.

Answer (score 7):

(I am not a lawyer.)

You may provide additional translations if youw lawyer permits, but:

- If your lawyer specifies that there is only one court of jurisdiction (the country where the lawsuit or dispute can be filed) then the language that is used for that jurisdiction would have to be marked as official, and the other translations have to be clearly marked as being provided for convenience only.
- If two or more translations are to be treated as official (for different jurisdictions), you may need to specify that in case of discrepancies, one of the translation should take precedence over all the other translations.

The basic idea is that there can not be ambiguities in the EULA - i.e. if the two translations of the EULA say two different things.

**Added**

If you have the EULA translated into the French language and then you're selling your software in both France and Canada, for example - your lawyer will need to customize the French-language EULA so that certain sections which only apply to France or to Canada are clearly labeled. (You may also store the two country-specific EULAs as two copies.)

This assumes your lawyer can read the language natively without the help of back-translation. Otherwise, the translated version has to be proofread by law firms in those countries, and you'll need to spend money.

(Once again - I am not a lawyer. Just some thoughts. Others with more knowledge are welcome to chime in.)

Answer (score 5):

We are using different application in a large enterprise in Germany. The applications are never internationalized and so are the EULAs. At least here in Germany, it is not generally expected to have a "native" EULA provided.
The internationalization of such a complex agreement is quite tricky and may have at least unexpected results as many figures of speech can not be translated verbatim. You may have had the experience with manuals automatically translated from asiatic languages.
**EDIT**
As Michael Borgwardt pointed out, translation is often the easy part. You would need an expert in international law to keep the EULA completely valid in all countries your software is distributed to.

Comment: There's the added factor that many EULA clauses (often the entire EULA) are void under German law.

Answer (score 0):

When i install a program from a big corporation it usually asks the language and then show the EULA in the chosen language. So yes.

Answer (score -3):

Time for a different approach!

The incomprehensible lawyer babble of license agreements just sucks. It  is most ridiculous that often one is expected to "Accept" it, where it is clear as pikestaff that nobody who hasn't attended a year or two at a law school really knows what he is accepting, that being a reason that in some countries such "agreements" are null and void from the outset, and rightly so.

Therefore, instead of stealing valuable time of people, just leave displaying the EULA out. You can have a link somewhere in case someone really wants to see it. This also answers your question regarding the language. Write it down in Klingon, nobody even will notice.

Comment: Not displaying it by default will probably leave the EULA null and void in every country.

Comment: So what? Can't we make software deals like with any other commodity? When did you last sign a End User Agreement at the filling station, saying that you agree to not use the gas you buy to commit illegal activities?

Answer (score -3):

For Germany you don't need to translate the EULA - it will not become effective in this juristication.

(I'm not a lawyer)

Comment: That's not true. EULAs (Endbenutzer-Lizenzverträge) are valid if they are valid under German law, and are shown to the customer and agreed to before purchasing a product.

Comment: @pyvi - This is nice "if they are valid under German law" - nobody - except perhaps the BVG - can tell that. 99.99% of users that are confronted with EULAs have not the slightest idea whether the 10+ pages are valid under German law.

Comment: @pyvi: Most EULA are shown after purchase on install